# Tkinter Entry() function is not working? The output has only one entry box instead of 3. What's the problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to Accept the use information in the form which I am making using ***tkinter*** but the problem is in the 2nd and 3rd entry function, there is no blank space to type anything. The input is only at the Name field.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *  

#Initialising the window  
top = tk.Tk()  
top.title('This is main')  
top.geometry('1000x500')  
top.minsize(500,250)  

#Accepting name of user  
nameprint=StringVar()  
name=tk.Label(text='Enter Your Name')  
name.pack()  
name_in=tk.Entry(textvariable=nameprint)
name_in.pack()

#Accepting Password
pwd_var=StringVar()
pwd=tk.Label(text='Create Password')
pwd.pack()
pwd_en=tk.Entry(textvariable=pwd_var)
name_in.pack()

#Confirming password
con_pwd_var=StringVar()
cnfm=tk.Label(text='Confirm Password')
cnfm.pack()
pwd_en=tk.Entry(textvariable=con_pwd_var)
name_in.pack()

#Heres the hello function 
def hello():
    abcd=nameprint.get()
    lb3=tk.Label(text=f'Your name is {abcd}')
    lb3.pack()

#The Button
bt1=tk.Button(text='Click me!',command=hello)
bt1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of my python script]

Comment: Here's my output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UyYk.png

Comment: You're calling `name_in.pack()` three times, and don't call `pack` on `pwd_en`, and you've used `pwd_en` twice. You've simply copied and pasted your own code incorrectly.

Comment: Yep I got that. Thank you @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.  Bryan Oakley said correct. In this code :

```
#Accepting Password
pwd_var=StringVar()
pwd=tk.Label(text='Create Password')
pwd.pack()
pwd_en=tk.Entry(textvariable=pwd_var)
name_in.pack()
```

Instead of pwd_en.pack() You wrote name_in.pack()
Please check your code.

Comment: Pls don't comment thanks. It is there in the stack overflow website. If you want to thank me you can press the check mark and make it green. No hate tho. Even I used to be like you when I started python tkinter LOL. :)